# How to integrate customer specific translation in django app

Tags: django, internationalization

We developped an app that will be used by several customer. The translation is working great. `django.po` & `django.mo` are generated and fields are translated in the app.

However for the same language we may have different translations according to the customer.

We would like to have something like like:

- customer1.po & .mo
- customer2.po & .mo

And in the django setting a parameter telling customer1 or customer2 thus django would use the one or the other translation file.

I've searched for changing the name of `django.po` to `customer1.po` but django seem to only look at `django.po/mo` files. Does someone knows a trick to do that ?

Comment: Do you have an example translation that changes per customer?.. Languages tend to differ per dialect and not per customer... Are you just trying to override part of a translation with customer specific info?

Comment: In fact we are trying to do both. The language specific part is related to technical wording that is related to the way people speak in their labs. But at the end, you are right we are trying to override with customer specific info.